# OWL Carousel Buttons do not have an accessible name

Tags: carousel, owl-carousel

I have this:
NAMES AND LABELS
Buttons do not have an accessible name
When a button doesn't have an accessible name, screen readers announce it as "button", making it unusable for users who rely on screen readers. Learn how to make buttons more accessible.

Failing Elements
div.col-md-12 > div.home-slider > div.owl-dots > button.owl-dot  div.col-md-12 > div.home-slider > div.owl-dots > button.owl-dot

Tried different solutions but none of them worked
need some help on this issue

Comment: Have you tried adding name='' to the buttons?  with the '' including the name such as 'ButtonName1'?  HTML uses names but javascript uses id's so maybe only one is set?

Answer (score 0):

To provide an accessible name for `<button>` use an attribute "aria-label". Use this section to tell what the button does e.g. for screen readers.

For example

```
<button aria-label="Slide 1" role="button" class="owl-dot active">
<button aria-label="Slide 2" role="button" class="owl-dot">
```

Replace "Slide 1" , "Slide 2" with what is the most appropriate description based on your circumstance.

Comment: tried, works, thanks

Comment: Great. Welcome to the Stack Overflow. Please mark as accepted answer. Since it helped you.